# Laravel 5.5 Method update doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to create a blog but I keep getting this error.

> BadMethodCallException
>   Method update does not exist.

I'm trying to edit posts and update the database.

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $posts = Post::Find($post);

    $posts->update($request->all());
}
```

Comment: What does your routes look like?

Comment: Please show the route and link or form that you use to execute the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are already accepting the Post object via the method

rather doing something like this

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $posts = Post::Find($post);

    $posts->update($request->all());
}
```

do it like this

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{  

    // you already have the Post object injected from the framework for you.
    // you can use the instance freely.
    $post->update($request->all());
}
```

of cause, it might be a good thing to check if the $post object is null or not but laravel will throw **ModelNotFoundException** if you don't have any matches in the database.

This is something called Route Model Binding which laravel 5.5 does for you if you keep the settings as default, as in using the primary key 'id'.
you can read more about this on this 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 4):

Do directly:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post) {

    $post->update($request->all());

}
```

`$post` is already an instance of `Post` model if the route was declared as:

```
Route::get('posts/update/{post}', 'PsotsController@update');
```

Doc Reference: [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding)

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = Post::find($post->id);
```

`find()` accepts only `primary id`